# Data store solution suitable for ID and timestamp based deduplication

Tags: java, database, amazon-dynamodb, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Java function (as a part of a Kafka Streams application) like this:

```
boolean isDuplicate(String key, long timestamp) {
    // TODO
}
```

This function needs to keep the key in some sort of data store and check if the same key was passed to this function within let's say 1 hour before and after the given timestamp.

For example, the table below shows a stream of input and the expected boolean result for each input:

| key | timestamp | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2024-02-02 13:30:00 | false // the data store is empty at this point, hence always false |
| A | 2024-02-02 13:30:00 | true // there was an input with the same key and the same timestamp, hence true |
| B | 2024-02-02 13:30:00 | false // this is a completely new key, hence false |
| A | 2024-02-02 12:30:00 | true // there was the same key within 1 hour, hence true |
| A | 2024-02-02 14:30:00 | true // there was the same key within 1 hour, hence true |
| A | 2024-02-02 14:30:01 | false // there was the same key but not within 1 hour, hence false |

The estimated number of unique keys is something close to 10 million now. This number is expected to keep growing.

There is also a strict performance requirement where one method call should be done within around a few milliseconds (ideally below 1 ms).

What can be the suitable data store solution for this problem?

Right now I've been using a Java collection framework based temporary solution (Kafka Streams in-memory state store) but I'm facing a scalability limitation due to the fact that it's all in-memory and the amount of the data I need to handle. I'm looking for an alternative (most probably an external separate data store) solution.

EDIT: One option which just popped up in my mind is using DynamoDB. Probably I can have a table where the partition key is the `key` and the sort key is the `timestamp`.

Comment: "10 million and expected to grow quickly" Grow quickly to 10 million, or grow quickly from 10 million to some other number?

Comment: The latter, the number is something close to 10 million now. This number is expected to keep growing.